# How to get the index of row containing min at one and max at second column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning

I am storing the information about trained models in a DataFrame:

```
                              score      time
LogisticRegression            1.0  0.257812
RidgeClassifier               1.0  0.283841
RandomForestClassifier        1.0  0.569159
GradientBoostingClassifier    1.0  9.408432
```

And I need to find the index (name) of the model, which has highest score and shortest time. How do I do that?

Comment: Plese read the description of the [tag:ml] tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sort_values` with ascending one side descending other side:

```
>>> df.sort_values(["score", "time"], ascending=[False, True]).index[0]
"LogisticRegression"
```

and get the 0th value in index in the result.